# XML Validation Error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'feed'

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I have created a XML file which is parsed by a parser. This is RSS atom file similar to [this](http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=1). It's a third party java parser and I am not aware about the additional details.

The XML file is

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'yes'?>
<?xml-stylesheet href='http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/capatom.xsl' type='text/xsl'?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:cap="urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2">
  <title type="text">Feeds Test</title>
  <subtitle type="text">Contains feeds generated by Me</subtitle>
  <id>uuid:1f48fcf1-cf2d-40bf-896f-e0f318e0fa52;id=1</id>
  <updated>2015-03-23T10:26:04Z</updated>
  <generator>MNS</generator>
  <link rel="self" type="text/html" title="TestRave Feeds" href="http://111.111.111.111//TestRave_atom_en_US.xml" />
  <entry>
    <id>6e21968e-ec73-46c8-bcf3-7bfb295ff59b</id>
    <title type="text">LAUNCHED : 3/23/2015 10:26:03 AM: Title for CAP notification message in English</title>
    <published>2015-03-23T10:26:03+05:30</published>
    <updated>2015-03-23T10:26:03+05:30</updated>
    <author>
      <email>myname@domain.com</email>
    </author>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://111.111.111.111//feed_6e21968e-ec73-46c8-bcf3-7bfb295ff59b_en_US.cap" />
    <content type="text">LAUNCHED : 3/23/2015 10:26:03 AM: Short Text for CAP message</content>
    <cap:records>3ae449ba-ec23-4c8d-9ea6-51d0078fd046</cap:records>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

At the time of parsing, the parser throws following error while processing XML.

> XML Validation Error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of
>   element 'feed'.

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Fancy giving us any clues about *what* parser you're feeding this XML into and/or what options/parameters you've provided to it?

Comment: Hi Damien: I am unaware of the third party java parser.

Comment: That error message is from Xerces, but a similar message should occur for any conformant validating XML parser. Clearly you have to associate an XSD with your XML in some manner. I show how to do it using `xsi:schemaLocation` in my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29209257/290085).  This is assuming that you do want validation; another option would be to configure your parser to be non-validating.

Comment: Closing it as it was the format of the text. At some places the format was BOM instead of UTF,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing it as it was the format of the text. At some places the format was BOM instead of UTF

Answer (score 0):

In your case, that error message is telling you that the parser cannot find an XSD that defines `feed` in the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace.   One way you could associate an XSD with your document instance is via `xsi:schemaLocation`:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
      xmlns:cap="urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
                          http://exyus.com/xcs/tasklist/source/?f=put_atom.xsd">
```

Note that `xsi:schemaLocation` takes namespace-location *pairs*.  I've taken the liberty of finding an Atom XSD for you that works.  You might want a different one or a different location for the same one.

You'll find that your next error is revealed to be due to you not having associated `urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2` with an XSD either.  You can resolve that problem similarly.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. This XML is nothing but replica of http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=1 using C# code. In the source of this page I did not find any link to any XSD.

Comment: I assure you that your error is due to the lack of association of your XML document instance with an XSD declaring your root element.  There are many mechanisms for making that association.  If you prefer not to (or cannot) modify the XML to make the association, you could use XML catalogs or other alternatives that tend to be more specific to your XML processor.